# EInvalidOp exception in Delphi

Tags: delphi, exception

my Delphi app raises an `EInvalidOp` exception on a user PC : **Invalid floating point operation**

here :

```
var
progress100 :extended;
taille_cur : int64;
i : Integer;

begin

...

progress100 := min(taille_cur div 2 * 100 / i, 99) // **raises the exception**


....
end;
```

I don't know why. 
It worked great when progress100 was an Integer. I changed it to Extended.
Or maybe variable `i` is zero...

please help.

Comment: Well, you are running the code. What values do the variables have? You failed to show us that information. Please provide a complete program.

Comment: I don't know why either, but if I were you I'd start by adding a few clarifying parentheses.

Comment: You're the only one who can debug this problem. Click on the line that starts with `progess100 :=` and press `F5`, then hit `F9` to run your program. When the breakpoint at that line is hit and your program stops, look at the contents of `i` and `taille_cur` (in that order), and you'll see exactly what's causing the problem. I'm voting to close this as "too localized", because we can't see the values of the variables while it runs to diagnose it.

Comment: It's also possible that `Min` isn't actually `Math.Min`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: If people would only check their preconditions (non-zero denominator) instead of making nonsense calls and then hoping that errors pop up so they can be handled. ;-)

Comment: @wouter That makes the code unreadable spaghetti. My app has thousands of expressions that can fail like this. Better to ask forgiveness than permission

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I just hope you're not advocating to add a try/catch in this example...

Comment: @Wouter Lord no! That would always be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I can see for that error to occur is for `i` to be equal to `0`.

This sort of problem is usually much easier to solve if you have the code running under the debugger. You can simply inspect the value of the expression's arguments and then it becomes clear as to why the fault occurs.

Comment: But wouldn't that raise a division by 0 exception, and not a "invalid floating point operation" exception?

Comment: @Mason No it would not

Comment: Really? I just tested it, and got: `Project Project1.exe raised exception class EZeroDivide with message 'Floating point division by zero'.`  So, in what circumstances would a division by zero in a Delphi program raise `EInvalidOp` and not `EZeroDivide`?

Comment: @Mason When I ran the code, invalid op was raised. XE3, vanilla console app, all variables equal to 0.

Comment: Aha! 0 / 0 raises EInvalidOp.  Anything else over 0 raises EZeroDivide, though.

Comment: @Mason Well done, glad we worked that out.